# Image path storted in db wont display

Tags: php, mysql

I have a image path stored the the database under *location* upload/imagename.png but I cant get it display on my page any help?

The images are stored in a image folder and in the database like image/name.png but can I take the path from the db and display it?

I have error reporting on but still nothing just a blank page.

```
<?php include_once('dbconnect.php'); ?>

<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>

<?php

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    //Get image path from database
    $result = $con->query("SELECT id, location FROM images WHERE id = {$_GET['id']} AND location = {$_GET['location']}");

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $imgData = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo '<img src='".$row['location']."' />';
    }else{
        echo 'Image not found...';
    }
}
?>
```

You access the page like *http://yoursite.com/recent.php?id=xxx*

EDIT: I tried this

```
<?php include_once('dbconnect.php'); ?>

<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>

<?php

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    //Get image data from database
    $result = $con->query("SELECT id, location FROM images WHERE id = {$_GET['id']} AND location = {$_GET['location']}");

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
       while($imgData = $result->fetch_assoc()){
           echo '<img src="'.$imgData['location'].'"/>';
       }
   }else{
        echo 'Image not found...';
   }
}
?>
```

Now I get

```
Notice: Undefined index: location in /home/vol15_4/epizy.com/epiz_20687250/yourwebprojects.22web.org/htdocs/3/recent.php on line 10

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/vol15_4/epizy.com/epiz_20687250/yourwebprojects.22web.org/htdocs/3/recent.php on line 12
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Is the image file is missing or you can't get the img tag as well?

Comment: If it is a blank page, then it doesn't display *Image not found...*, so presumably the URL is just wrong.

Comment: You've not defined `$row` anywhere.

Comment: I'm surprised that doesn't report `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';'` though.

Comment: The images are stored in a image folder and in the database like image/name.png but can I take the path from the db and display it?

Comment: Looks like your `$_Get[]` global does not contain a `Location` index so `$result` is blowing up. Check your query param.

Comment: Ok hold up I will check in a bit so I still have the errors but now it says “Image not found”.

Comment: I seem to cant fix. Any suggestions / help?

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly getting an undefined error for `$row`:

```
 if($result->num_rows > 0){
       while($imgData = $result->fetch_assoc()){
           echo '<img src="'.$imgData['location'].'"/>';
       }
   }else{
        echo 'Image not found...';
   }
```

Comment: So I updated the code with the one above now I get Notice: Undefined  index: location in /home/vol15_4/epizy.com/epiz_20687250/yourwebprojects.22web.org/htdocs/3/recent.php on line 10

 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/vol15_4/epizy.com/epiz_20687250/yourwebprojects.22web.org/htdocs/3/recent.php on line 12

Comment: `var_dump($imgData)` and start from there

Comment: I edited the post with the new code when I got the errors if you would like to take a look that will be nice.

Comment: I seem to cant fix. Any suggestions / help?